# XNA 4.0 + DirectX 9?

Tags: c#, xna, directx

I'm using `XNA 4.0` and `Visual Studio 2010` and when I create an XNA project and publish it, it doesn't work on a computer with DirectX 9.0c (no DX10/11).

As I understand it, the project is set to DX10 by default.

**Is there any way to make a project DX9 compliant?

How can I create a new project that is DX9 compliant from the start?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the game profile from Hi-Def to Reach, in project properties.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/12/reach-vs-hidef.aspx

Comment: How much would that *really* limit me? Perhaps downgrading to XNA 3.1 would be better than using 4.0 + Reach?

Comment: Well, depends what kind of game/project you're making, I guess. The link I posted has an overview table. I've only used 4.0 myself (and I only started recently), so I can't really offer you helpful advice on that.

Comment: My target is the PC / Windows platform. Thanks anyway.

Comment: FWIW, I just switched my current (simple) project from Hi-Def to Reach, and it works fine, and looks exactly the same. My guess is you'll be fine on Reach, unless you specifically want to use some advanced techniques that aren't available there.

Comment: I don't think I need anything overcomplicated, so this is good to hear.